# Sourcing data from DocumentDB in Hadoop

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-cosmosdb

I have a hadoop application that source data from two different DocumentDB collection. However, the json schema of documents belonging to these two collections are different. Both has a field showing time, but one is called TimeStamp and the other one is called UpdatedOn. I'd like to know how I can specify a query which is based on this time field and retrive only those json documents satisfying the condition in my query. I specify my query like below

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Timestamp > " + timestamp;
conf.set(ConfigurationUtil.QUERY, query);
```

This query applies on one of the collection. I need a query like below

```
"SELECT * FROM collection1 as c1, collection2 as c2 WHERE c1.Timestamp > x1 OR c2.UpdatedOn > x1"
```

Is this supported in DocumentDB?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported since it is not documented, your best bet is two execute these two queries and then merge the results using Linq or any other technique to get one result set.

Hope this helps.